# Proof of property of orthogonal complement.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $M$ be a non-empty subspace of unitary space $X$. Prove that $\overline{Lin(M)}=X$ if and only if $M^{\perp}=\{0\}$.

I know that $M^{\perp}=\{0\}$ would mean that  $x \perp M$ implies $x=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "unitary space" ?

Comment: A vector space where the inner product is given.

Comment: All right, a synonym to the term (pre-)Hilbert space.